# Magento - SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, soap

Pessoal estou com este erro e infelizmente não consigo resolver o mesmo.

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://magento.cordeirosilva.adv.br/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1'

Meu codigo.

$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magento.cordeirosilva.adv.br/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('xxxx', 'xxxxx'); $result = $proxy->catalogCategoryTree($sessionId); var_dump($result);

O que estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: You probably should use this address: http://magento.cordeirosilva.adv.br/rest/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

Comment: Wouldn't This case be REST instead of SOAP?

Comment: In your case it is: http://magento.cordeirosilva.adv.br/soap?wsdl&services=customerV1. See the Magento documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/soap/soap-web-api-calls.html